# Python Package: Import submodule and rename it?

Tags: python, import, namespaces, git-submodules

I'm creating a `timecode` python package with the following layout:

```
timecode/
    __init__.py
    timecode.py
    timecoderange.py
    modes.py
```

`timecode.py` contains a class called `Timecode`.  `timecoderange.py` contains a class for `TimecodeRange`.  `modes.py` contains an abstract class and a few subclasses (`DropFrame` and `NonDropFrame`) which are intended for use with both the `Timecode` and `TimecodeRange` classes.

---

When someone uses my timecode library, I would like them to be able to import things like this:

```
from timecode import Timecode, TimecodeRange, Modes
```

...so that they can refer to modes under that `Modes` namespace:

```
tc = Timecode("01:00:00:00", mode=Modes.NonDropFrame())
```

---

**So this finally brings me to my question**: how do I bring in my `modes` submodule as `Modes` (capital `M`)?  In `__init__.py` I've tried:

```
from . import modes as Modes
```

But this does not work.  When I later try to use the `timecode` library using `from timecode import Modes`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'timecode.Modes'`.

Comment: `from . import modes as Modes` should be correct, if it doesn't work you have a different problem.

Comment: Can you make sure that you are not confusing the `timecode` directory with the `timecode.py` module by giving them different names?

Comment: @mkrieger1 You know what, you're right.  I think the problem is now in `timecode.py`, where I have `from .Modes import NonDropFrame`.  However if I do `from . import Modes` and then use it as `Modes.NonDropFrame`, that works.  So I guess I have more to learn about relative imports or something.